# contraction kernel nonnegativity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $T$ be a contraction (i.e. $||T||\leq1$) on a Hilbert space and
> for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
> let$$K_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\right)(T^k+{T^*}^k)$$be
> its Fejér kernel . Prove by an elementary method (i.e. without the use
> of spectral theory or dilation theory) that $K_n\geq0$ for all
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$ .

This problem appeared in American Mathematical Monthly journal . In general it is known that Fejér kernel is a non-negative kernel (at least in the Fourier analysis sense) . But this problem extends that to arbitrary contraction operators . I would like to see a solution (even using spectral theory/dilation theory , if the elementary method is not so nice) . Regards .

Comment: If $T$ is a unitary operator then by the spectral theorem the problem reduces to the Fourier series. If $T$ is a contraction by dilation theorem of Nagy, there is a larger space such that $T^n=PU^nP$ for $n\ge 1$ and $P$ is the orthogonal projection from the larger space onto $H.$  I do not know an elementary solution.

Comment: If $\|T\|<1$ or for $1\notin \sigma(T)$ it might be possible  to get an elementary solution by applying formulas for
$x+x^2+\ldots +x^n$ and $x+2x^2+\ldots +nx^n$